# Open aura:application from link on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, field-service-lightning

I am building a Lightning application as this:

```
<aura:application description="AppDescription"
                  implements="force:appHostable"
                  extends="force:slds"
>

  <aura:attribute name="recordId"        type="String"   access="public" />

  <c:MyComponent recordId="{! v.recordId}" />
</aura:application>
```

This is accessible from link `https://myOrg.lightning.force.com/c/MyApp.app?recordId=ABCD`

Our users will be using **Field Service Lightning Mobile App** and **Salesforce1**, the first application provides a link to the `aura:application` (MyApp).

Is it possible to open this application from Salesforce1 ? My first try is to access the app from my browser and then click on "open with Salesforce1" but it opens in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to access this **Lightning App** (https://myOrg.lightning.force.com/c/MyApp.app?recordId=ABCD)

1. Create a Connected App(Under Manage Apps>New Connected App) and
   specify the Lightning App URL as the **Start URL** and **Mobile
   Start URL**. You can then add the App to the App Launcher and to
   Salesforce1 Navigation Menu, u so that you can launch the app
   directly from there(Make the App available for desired profiles).
2. Another method is to create a Web Tab and mention the Lightning App
   URL and make the Web Tab available in Salesforce1 navigation.

Comment: Hey @Hermant Jain, thanks for the answer.

For the first solution, I am not getting which URL I need to put to fit Sandbox and Production URL. (myorg--pc and myorg).

Comment: I feel you will have to configure the URL separately for Production and Sandbox. The URL that is generated when you preview the app from developer console

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but it does not work.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: The URL still does not open sf1 at good page, better case: black page after app loading

Comment: Have you hardcoded the record Id in the URL? how are you passing the record Id?

Comment: The record Id is not hardcoded, I would like to generate the URL with the Id then redirect on click.